# Google Drive API: Getting properties for a large number of files

Tags: google-drive-api

I have an application which manages file metadata on Google Drive, and naturally stores it as [`properties`](https://developers.google.com/drive/properties) on the files. Since this application needs the metadata for all files when loading, I end up making hundreds of requests of [Properties: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/properties/list)

```
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/properties/list
```

- one of these for each file my app manages.

Is there a way to get the properties in bulk for all files in a folder?

[Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list) supports adding the field `items/properties` to its `fields` parameter, so clearly the thought occured to someone that this should be possible, but that field is never populated. Am I doing something wrong or is this just not an option?

Comment: This question is also bugging my brains. Have you found any solution for this?

Comment: I found an API for batching requests, `gapi.client.newRpcBatch` (https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs#gapiclientRpcBatch). It's deprecated though, in favour of an API called `HttpBatch`, but I never got that one to work with the rest of Drive's JS API.

Comment: P.S. some of the APIs don't even recognize that the requests are batched and have a rate limit which I've hit with a single batch request. For example, a request to call `drive.parents.insert` on 89 files succeeded for 44 files and failed for the rest.